# Async requests in PHP

Tags: php, javascript, http, asynchronous, request

I need to generate requests to several APIs, get response from them and then generate a report.

something like this:

```
foreach($api_array as $api){
    echo $api;

    $responce = file_get_contents($api);

    if($responce) 
        echo 'ok <br/>';
    else 
        echo 'fail <br/>';
}
```

It's obvious that when run consistently, one by one, this will take A LOT of time to wait for each service to respond.

Can this be done asynchronously, like in JavaScript? Thanks a lot!

Comment: If you do not need to process the results, you can start a [separate PHP process in the background](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/45953/php-execute-a-background-process) but PHP itself does not know the concept of asynchronous requests (because a PHP script runs from top to bottom as opposed to a JavaScript in the browser that can be triggered by events). That said, the [`curl_multi`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-select.php) family of functions does something that comes close

Comment: http://www.onlineaspect.com/2009/01/26/how-to-use-curl_multi-without-blocking/

Comment: thanks everyone, I'll chose the best method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [curl_multi](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-init.php) for this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do that using `curl_multi` that will do it in parallel. 
You can also use a callback to get the reponses like in this example
http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/php/examples/callbacks.html

Also read more on `curl_multi` here http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-init.php[2](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-init.php)